How to break multiple try catch blocks in powershell
I have a class with +- 25 API functions for which I want to write a test-script.
I test my API-functions before and after a software upgrade so that I'm sure everything remains working.
However, I have an issue. I want to stop my script if certain functions stop working or return the wrong data. how would I approach this if my script exists of try / catch blocks?
is putting a break and the output of my successes/errors the best practise? or are there better alternatives to tackle this?
$API = [API]::NEW()
$SuccessString
$ErrorString

function TestAPIs{

try{
    
    $PersonID = $API.GetPersonByName("test")
    if($PersonID.id -eq 1)
    {
        $SuccessString += "API function getpersonbyname OK"
    }else
    {
        $ErrorString += "error!!! function returns invalid row!"   
    }

}catch{
       $ErrorString += "critical error: " + $_.Exception.Message
       }


try{
    
    $Permissions = $API.GetPermissions($PersonID)
    if($Permissions.Records -gt 1)
    {
        $SuccessString += "API function getpermissions OK"
    }else
    {
        $ErrorString += "error!!! permissions returns invalid row!"   
    }

}catch{
       $ErrorString += "critical error: " + $_.Exception.Message
   write-host $SuccessString
   write-host $ErrorString
   BREAK
       }
}


sounds like you're looking for pester: https://pester.dev/

i cant use third party modules sadly

so the question is how you can exit early your test function if one test fails? if so you can $PSCmdlet.ThrowTerminatingError or just throw in your catch block

Given your sample code, if you want to stop executing more tests from within one of the catch blocks you can just return from your function - that will return control back to the calling code. You can also return a value if the calling code needs to know whether any tests failed, or a more complex structure if you want to pass more detailed test results (like y’know, pester does :-)).

In fact, each test could just use write-output to send a single “pass” or”fail” test result as a pscustomobject to the function’s output stream, and use return to exit on a test failure - the calling code can receive the test results and display them however it wants (console, write to disk, throw if there’s a failure, etc). That separates rest execution from result handling.

@user3127554 Windows 10/2016 and up ship with Pester 3.4.0

If you can't use Pester, you can at least cherry-pick some concepts and make a (very) basic version (so basic in fact, it's almost embarrassing to be caught comparing it to Pester :-).
The key parts are:

returning structured pscustomobject result objects rather than writing to the console - the calling code can decide what to do with the results

exiting the test function early with return if a particular failed test means the test run should end


function TestAPIs {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        $APIObject
    )

    $testName = "GetPersonByName"
    try {
        $PersonID = $API.GetPersonByName("test")
        if($PersonID.id -eq 1) {
            [pscustomobject] @{
                "Name"        = $testName
                "Success"     = $true
                "Description" = "API function getpersonbyname OK"
            }
        }
        else {
            [pscustomobject] @{
                "Name"        = $testName
                "Success"     = $false
                "Description" = "error!!! function returns invalid row!"
            }
        }
    }
    catch {
        [pscustomobject] @{
            "Name"        = $testName
            "Success"     = $false
            "Description" = "critical error: " + $_.Exception.Message
        }
    }

    $testName = "GetPermissions"
    try {
        $Permissions = $API.GetPermissions($PersonID)
        if($Permissions.Records -gt 1) {
            [pscustomobject] @{
                "Name"        = $testName
                "Success"     = $true
                "Description" = "API function getpermissions OK"
            }
        }
        else {
            [pscustomobject] @{
                "Name"        = $testName
                "Success"     = $false
                "Description" = "error!!! permissions returns invalid row!"
            }
            # DON'T RUN ANY MORE TESTS IF THIS TEST FAILS
            return
        }
    }
    catch {
        [pscustomobject] @{
            "Name"       = $testName
            "Success"    = $false
            "Description" = "critical error: " + $_.Exception.Message
        }
        # DON'T RUN ANY MORE TESTS IF THIS TEST FAILS
        return
   }

   # ... more tests ...

}

To use it:
$API = [API]::new()

# the foreach-object outputs each individual result to the console
# as they are generated rather then waiting for all results to
# complete before showing anything amd *also* passes the value through
# to $results (so a sort of Tee-Object)
$results = TestAPIs -APIObject $API `
    | foreach-object {
        write-host ($_ | format-list | out-string);
        $_
    }

which outputs this:
Name        : GetPersonByName
Success     : False
Description : critical error: You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.

Name        : GetPermissions
Success     : False
Description : critical error: You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.

and populates the $results variable so you can do things like:
if( $results.Success -contains $false )
{
    throw "one or more tests failed"
}

Ultimately, if you can use Pester you should, but if you can't then the above might give a small step up from where your code already was...

If I understand correctly the question you can use Cmdlet.ThrowTerminatingError to throw a pipeline terminating exception, meaning the function ends as soon as a critical error occurs.
function TestAPIs {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [API] $APIObject
    )

    try {
        $PersonID = $APIObject.GetPersonByName('test')
        if ($PersonID.id -eq 1) {
            Write-Host 'API function getpersonbyname OK' -ForegroundColor Green
        }
        else {
            # you can use `$PSCmdlet.WriteError(...)` here
            # if you want to customize your ErrorRecord object
            # by default, if `$ErrorActionPreference` is `Continue`
            # both options will output an error but do not stop the function
            Write-Error 'error!!! function returns invalid row!'
        }
    }
    catch {
        Write-Error 'Critical Error Ocurred'
        $PSCmdlet.ThrowTerminatingError($_) # <= This stops immidiately the pipeline
    }

    try {
        $Permissions = $APIObject.GetPermissions($PersonID)
        if ($Permissions.Records -gt 1) {
            Write-Host 'API function getpermissions OK' -ForegroundColor Green
        }
        else {
            Write-Error 'error!!! permissions returns invalid row!'
        }
    }
    catch {
        Write-Error 'Critical Error Ocurred'
        $PSCmdlet.ThrowTerminatingError($_)
    }
}

$API = [API]::new()
TestAPIs -APIObject $API

